# Is this a $c^\infty$ Atlas?

Tags: manifolds

I'm watching Frederic Schuller's "Lectures on the Geometric Anatomy of Theoretical Physics," and came across the following in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa6SRAwY80Y&t=1200) video: We want to define an atlas on the real line with the standard topology. We choose the atlas to be $\mathscr{A} = \{ (\mathbb{R},x) \}$ where $x(a)=\sqrt[3] a.$

Schuller states that this is a $C^{\infty}$ atlas. I'm confused about how this can be since $\sqrt[3] a$ is not differentiable at 0. Am I misunderstanding definitions here or has Schuller made a mistake?

Answer (score 7):

You want the *transition functions* to be smooth, you don't give a damn about the charts themselves.

Comment: Would that mean any valid atlas with a single chart is $C^\infty$?

Comment: @Dargscisyhp Well, you need the chart map to be continuous and bijective, of course, but yes.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer!